# add an error message on script for osclass

Tags: javascript, html

how do I add an error message in this script:

```
$('input[name="s_postby"]').attr("required", false); // put the id of the input field that you whant required

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#catId').change(function(){
  if( $('#catId').val() == "28" || $('#catId').val() == "29" || 
$('#catId').val() == "30" || $('#catId').val() == "31")
    {
       $("#postby").hide();  // change Posted By with ID you give to the div
    $('input[name="s_postby"]').attr("required", false); // put the id of the input field that you whant required
    }else
    {
        $("#postby").show(); // change Posted By with ID you give to the div
    $('input[name="s_postby"]').attr("required", true); // put the id of the input field that you whant required
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the error message to debug, you can use the console.log() function inside the script. Or if you prefer seeing it on the popup you can use an alert() function in the script. If you want to the user to see the error message then you can create a div with the error message as its content and hide/show the div.

For dynamically setting the error message you can use document.getElementById function to get the DOM element and then use the innerText property to set the text of the DOM element to a error message.Please find the example below:

```
var mydiv = document.getElementById("id_of_the_div");
mydiv.innerText = "myErrorMessage";
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // Code for form validation
        $("form[name=contact_form]").validate({
            rules: {
                message: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 1
                },

Comment: yourEmail: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                }
            },

Comment: messages: {
                yourEmail: {
                    required: "Email: this field is required.",
                    email: "Invalid email address."
                },
                message: {
                    required: "Message: this field is required.",
                    minlength: "Message: this field is required."
                }
            },

Comment: errorLabelContainer: "#error_list",
            wrapper: "li",
            invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
                $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $('h1').offset().top }, { duration: 250, easing: 'swing'});
            },
            submitHandler: function(form){
                $('button[type=submit], input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                form.submit();
            }
        });
    });
</script>

Comment: you can use the document.getElementById function of javascript to get the div and then set the innerText property of the div to a error message.

Comment: how to do this Sir?